# helm charts index.yaml on an Artficatory repository has wrong urls (local://.. instead of https://..)

Tags: kubernetes-helm, artifactory, jfrog-cli

On my job, we have an Artifactory cloud subscription,
In there we have a repository of type "local" on Artifactory for storing our Helm charts.

Whenever a new chart is uploaded as a `tar.gz` file, it is indexed automatically by Artifactory

But the `index.yaml` file has the **wrong URL**, thus when we try to use the charts it fails

**Problem:** url on local repository index.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
entries:
  my-chart:
  - apiVersion: v1
    created: 2021-03-11T15:25:37.652038Z
    description: my chart
    digest: 195ae085341f4455eb9ccc3f35cf4f9b0a29f452a948664aefb43e8c05bc575a
    name: my-chart
    urls:
    - local://my-chart-2.0.1.tgz    # <-- here is the problem (local://...)
    version: "2.0.1"
```

**Expected behavior**: The correct index.yaml would be like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
entries:
  my-chart:
  - apiVersion: v1
    created: 2021-03-11T15:25:37.652038Z
    description: my chart
    digest: 195ae085341f4455eb9ccc3f35cf4f9b0a29f452a948664aefb43e8c05bc575a
    name: my-chart
    urls:
    - https://<my-company>.jfrog.io/artifactory/my-local-repo/my-chart-2.0.1.tgz # <- valid url
    version: "2.0.1"
```

**Error**: If I try to pull the chart, I get the following message:

> Error: scheme "local" not supported

**Confusion**:
I have tried creating the same structure in my private jFrog account and **could not replicate the behavior**

Comment: can you confirm you have a custom base URL set? Navigate to UI --> Administration --> General | Settings? If not set, set it your Artifactory URL and test it out.

Comment: @MuhammedKashif
Sadly, I couldn't find this option in our installation

Comment: whats you Artifactory version?

Comment: @MuhammedKashif we are using the cloud version of jfrog

Answer (score 0):

Artifactory only supports resolving charts from a virtual helm repository:

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Kubernetes+Helm+Chart+Repositories#KubernetesHelmChartRepositories-ResolvingHelmCharts

You need to create a virtual repository that aggregates the local repository and point the helm client to it.